# @Html.ActionLink is not linking to current area by default

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink, html.actionlink, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have 2 areas `Admin` and `FrontEnd` (in that order).

When I am in a view in my FrontEnd area, `ActionLink` always points to the `Admin` area:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Checkout", "Address", "Checkout")
```

Will be `http://localhost:53600/admin/Checkout/Address` but the Checkout controller is in my FrontEnd area.

I know I can solve this by specifying a routedata object in the action link and setting `area = "FrontEnd"` but I don't want to. I want the `ActionLink` helper to default to my current route.

Is this possible?

All the questions I've read on actionlink are people asking how to link to another area which indicates it defaults to the current area for them. Am I alone with this issue?

Edit, these are my routes which you can see are tied to the correct namespace:

**Admin**

```
public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Administration_default",
        "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "Administration", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "CC.Web.Areas.Administration.Controllers" }
        );
}
```

**FrontEnd**

```
public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute("Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "FrontEnd", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
        new[] {"CC.Web.Areas.FrontEnd.Controllers"}
        );
}
```

Comment: Are you really using areas? If so, you should be using the `AreaRegistration` classes to register those areas and its routes. See the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.arearegistration(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: It also looks like the FrontEnd shouldn't be an area, so you could just have the standard MVC controllers and views with an additional Admin area.

Comment: @DanielJ.G. I read that about 15 mins ago and noticed this is the issue. It has also fixed my problem. Feel free to post an answer along those lines and I'll accept (although I just found it anyway). Thanks for the area advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Areas should be registered in classes deriving from `AreaRegistration` overriding the method `void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)`, see the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.arearegistration(v=vs.118).aspx).

The `AreaRegistrationContext` defines its [own methods](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AreaRegistrationContext.cs) to register area routes that will add the required dataTokens for the areas that are used when generating links and urls:

```
public Route MapRoute(string name, string url, object defaults, object constraints, string[] namespaces)
{
    if (namespaces == null && Namespaces != null)
    {
        namespaces = Namespaces.ToArray();
    }

    Route route = Routes.MapRoute(name, url, defaults, constraints, namespaces);
    route.DataTokens[RouteDataTokenKeys.Area] = AreaName;

    // disabling the namespace lookup fallback mechanism keeps this areas from accidentally picking up
    // controllers belonging to other areas
    bool useNamespaceFallback = (namespaces == null || namespaces.Length == 0);
    route.DataTokens[RouteDataTokenKeys.UseNamespaceFallback] = useNamespaceFallback;

    return route;
}
```

It also looks like the FrontEnd shouldn't be an area, so you could just have the standard MVC controllers and views (instead of the fronteand area) with an extra Admin area:

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Administration";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Administration_default",
            "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "CC.Web.Areas.Administration.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

Remember that you should be calling `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` at the beggining of your main RegisterRoutes method invoked on app start.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, much appreciated. Oddly enough, I was already calling the `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` I just didn't have the routes setup to derive from `AreaRegistration`.